# Cannot show maximize/minimize rectangle button for window resizing in android app Chromebook?

Tags: android, window, chromebook

My app requires resizing  "maximizing" screen size (using [] maximize button in top right corner) while running in a ***chromebook***.This button is showing in other android apps like google keep, a sample bare bones app I created  by default.

However, it is not showing in my current project and it is by default shown in full screen. "compileSDKVersion" is 25 and "targetSDKversion" is 23.Earlier I had attribute "resizeableactivity" set as false, I re-checked app after setting it to true or removing the all the occurrences of that attribute itself, but doesn't help.Do suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing **targetSDKversion** to **24 or higher** solved the issue. You can try this.